# In the context of Russell's Paradox.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While reading about Russell's Paradox, I encountered an example stating 
"if x is the set of all natural numbers, then the set of all natural numbers is not a natural number". What does this statement mean?

Comment: It means what it says, what do you mean what does it mean?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Russell's Paradox version of commenting. :))

Comment: The [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) are the "counting" numbers : $0,1,2,\ldots$. The set $\mathbb N$ of **all** natural numbers is not a natural number (the set of all Latin poets is not a poet at all).

Comment: Are you sure you've copied that statement correctly? It's not false, but as written the protasis is completely irrelevant - it would be better written as just "The set of all natural numbers is not a natural number" (since after being introduced, $x$ doesn't come up again).

Comment: If x is the set of all natural numbers, then x ∉ x (The set of all natural numbers is not a natural number). That's the full statement. @NoahSchweber

Comment: That's better, now at least $x$ is actually being used in the statement.